# Linux: Onscreen swipe keyboard

Tags: keyboard, touch-screen, accessibility

I injured my hand so that typing is now difficult.  I have a touchscreen monitor on my laptop and am running Debian.  Is there an on-screen keyboard which has swipe capabilities like the [Google Keyboard](https://youtu.be/-zWowDurQyo) on my android device?  I know of [Florence Keyboard](http://florence.sourceforge.net/english.html) and [several alternatives](http://florence.sourceforge.net/english/alternatives.html), but they don't seem to have swiping.